# Wordpress : The specified URL cannot be found

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, http

WordPress Version : 3.8.3, I cannot upgrade the version due to theme compatibility issue.

I'm getting "The specified URL cannot be found." error whenever I click Update Page/Post/Editor or click Save button in any of the plugins.

This is definitely not a permalink issue because I already tried changing the permalink to the default one.

Some History, I developed the wordpress in my dev server with another domain and I transferred all the files to Live Server (I have limited access to this server, I need to go through the server admin every time I need to change something) by zipping all the file and exporting the DB. For the DB I already change the SiteURL and also Home using search and replace.

Is there anything that I missed out which causing the above error?
Is is something to do with apache, .htaccess or server permission?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following steps
1. Backup your .htaccess
2. Clear or empty your .htaccess
3. Login to your WordPress Dashboard, save your website URL and blog URL in wp-admin > settings > general
4. Save your permalinks settings again

Did you update your plugins? If you did update your plugins, it could cause this problem because plugins may change their codes to adapt with latest WordPress. Just keep your plugins,don't update it while you still on WordPress 3.8.3

Also check server configuration. Server could blocking all the POST requests with lot of data.

Comment: "Also check server configuration. Server could blocking all the POST requests with lot of data."

How to check server configuration?

Comment: How to check server configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You might require to define following permissions to .htaccess file..

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Reference http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with one of my customer's website. It was only a single page that showed the symptoms. Changed the permalink-structure, removed the .htaccess -> so success. Then I went a completely different approach. I tried to find out what's the difference between that one single not working page and all the others. So I removed all the content and meta-data and boom... it worked. Adding all that stuff back one by one I found out it has to be in the content.

**Solution:**
My client linked to another site which contained the '~'-character within the url. This made Wordpress crash!

So... **look out for non-encoded special characters** in our source!